# Can I retrospectively exclude certain IP addresses from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I couldn't find anything definitive for this question You can set up filters on Google Analytics but it's not clear whether this works retrospectively or just prevents any future visits from the excluded IPs appearing.

My marketing department (bless them) believe that certain IP addresses are skewing our analytics data and want to exclude them from our reports. Is there a way to exclude these addresses back to when we started collecting data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Filters for a view do not work for historical data. And you can't filter IP addresses in t he reports because IP addresses are not a valid dimension (for one thing Google does not show IP addresses because of privacy concerns).

However if the offending visits all come from the same IP address there is a good chance that they have more things in common, like user agent string, or they are all calling a single page etc. Try to find a pattern that you can filter out with a segment (segments do not remove data from you profile, but they can filter historical data).

Answer (score 3):

You **can** filter on network domain.  So, you could exclude the network domain of the offending IP address.  We are able to use this approach sometimes, like to exclude traffic coming from our own servers on Amazon (that are doing health checks, for example).

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you put the exclusion in Segment then you can apply it to historical data.  If you put the exclusion in a View Filter then it only filters out data going forward.